# add-apt-repository: command not found in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java

I installed my VPS with Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit and I even checked with

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

and I got

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS"
```

However, I'm getting `add-apt-repository: command not found` error while I try to install JVM.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add-apt-repository` isn't installed by default. You have to install the `python-software-properties` package first.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```