# Ubuntu 12.10, can't seem to get add-apt-repository

Tags: ubuntu

I am attempting to add some external packages to Ubuntu 12.10 from a PPA. To do so, I need to use `add-apt-repository`. Easy enough - [add-apt-repository: command not found in Ubuntu 10.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/192919/add-apt-repository-command-not-found-in-ubuntu-10-04) tells me to install `python-software-properties`. I have done that - here's proof that it is already there:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
```

Yet, I still don't have `add-apt-repository`:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo add-apt-repository
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
user@hostname:~$ add-apt-repository
The program 'add-apt-repository' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-software-properties
 * software-properties-common
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

What (obvious?) thing am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it almost immediately after asking the question. I need both packages - I added `software-properties-common` and I am good. Although that was not at all obvious to me from the error.